# Checking whether a number is a Smith number

Tags: java, time-limit-exceeded, primes

I have created a Java program to check if the number entered by the user is a [Smith number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_number) (a number whose sum of digits equals the sum of the digits of its prime factorization). The program works fine but takes too long to check numbers like 4937775. How do I reduce the time taken by it to execute?

```
import java.util.*; 
class check
{
    static boolean a;
    static boolean checkprime(long n)
    {
        int i, factors= 0; 
        for(i = 1;i<=n ;i++)
        {
            if(n%i==0)
                factors++;
        }
        if(factors == 2)
            return true;
        else
            return false; 
    }

    static long sumfinder(long  n)
    {
        long  sum = 0; 
        while(n!=0)
        {
            sum = sum + n%10; 
            n= n/10; 
        }
        return sum; 
    }

    static boolean checksmith(long  n)
    {
        long  sum = 0; 
        if(checkprime(n)== true)
        { 
            System.out.println(n + " is a prime number ");
            return false; 
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(n + " is not  a prime number ");
            //generate prime factors: 
            long  num = n; 

            outer: 
            for(long  i = 1; i<= num ; i++)
            {
                if(checkprime(i)== true)
                {

                    if(num%i== 0)
                    {
                        sum= sum+ sumfinder(i); 
                        num = num/i; 
                        i = 1;
                        if (num == 1)
                        {
                            break outer; 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
        System.out.println(sumfinder(n));

        if (sumfinder(n)== sum)

            return true; 

        else
            return false;
    }

    static void display()throws InputMismatchException
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        long  n = sc.nextInt(); 
        if(checksmith(n)== true)
        {
            System.out.println("Smith number");

        }
        else
            System.out.println("Not a Smith number");
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        display(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> class check
> ```

Java naming convention is that class names should start with an uppercase letter. `Check` is also not very informative: *what* does it check?

---

> ```
>     static boolean a;
> ```

Is this used anywhere?

---

> ```
>     static boolean checkprime(long n)
> ```

Again, Java naming convention is that (a) camel-case should be used (`checkPrime` instead of `checkprime`); (b) Boolean-valued properties should *generally* have names beginning `is` (`isPrime` instead of `checkPrime`). In this case `isPrime` reads quite naturally in context (e.g. `if (isPrime(n)) ...`).

---

> ```
>         int i, factors= 0; 
>         for(i = 1;i<=n ;i++)
>         {
>             if(n%i==0)
>                 factors++;
>         }
>         if(factors == 2)
>             return true;
>         else
>             return false;
> ```

Why give `i` such a wide scope?

Why use `factors` at all? If you find a divisor which is not `1` or `n` you can `return false` immediately.

What's going on with the whitespace in `for(i = 1;i<=n ;i++)`? The semicolon separates expressions: I can't understand why you'd want whitespace inside the expression `i = 1` but not after the semicolon which separates the `1` from `i<=n`.

There are much faster ways to test primality. Aside from the comments made in another answer about only testing up to `sqrt(n)`, look around for discussion on BPSW or just use `BigInteger.isProbablePrime`.

---

> ```
>     static long sumfinder(long  n)
> ```

Again, names. If the name of a method is a noun, I expect it to describe the object returned: but the `long` returned is not a sum-finder. It's the sum. I suggest that a better name for this method would be `digitSum`.

---

> ```
>     {
>         long  sum = 0; 
>         while(n!=0)
>         {
>             sum = sum + n%10; 
>             n= n/10; 
>         }
>         return sum; 
>     }
> ```

I understand this to be at the level of throwaway code rather than production: if it were production code, I'd expect to see either some code to handle the case `n < 0` or a comment to explain why that is unnecessary.

---

> ```
>     static boolean checksmith(long  n)
> ```

See previous comments on names.

Existing answers propose some better ways to write the body of this method; I want to focus as much on general points of style as on algorithms, although I do have one or two points to add there too.

---

> ```
>         long  sum = 0;
> ```

Which sum? There are two relevant sums, right?

> ```
>         if(checkprime(n)== true)
> ```

`== true` is a crime against [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

> ```
>             System.out.println(n + " is a prime number ");
> ```

That's an unexpected side effect.

> ```
>             //generate prime factors:
> ```

I'm not sure what exactly the scope of this comment is, but I wouldn't describe the following loop as *generating prime factors*.

> ```
>             outer:
> ```

?? There's no inner loop, so what purpose does this label serve?

> ```
>             for(long  i = 1; i<= num ; i++)
> ```

That should strike terror into the heart of anyone who wants their program to terminate in a reasonable time. There are three possible cases: (a) `i` could perfectly well be an `int`; (b) `i` gets incremented by more than `1` elsewhere; (c) this loop will execute more than \$2^{31}\$ times. Here it's not case (b), so which of the other two is it?

(Aside: the rewrites correctly observe that you only need to go up to `sqrt(n)`, but if `n` is a long that could still be about \$2^{31.5}\$. It might be worth looking at faster factorisation methods, starting with Pollard's rho).

> ```
>                 if(checkprime(i)== true)
>                 {
>                     if(num%i== 0)
> ```

In addition to previous comments, why check whether `i` is prime? That check is slower than the `num % i` check, and if the second check succeeds then the first one must also for basic number-theoretic reasons.

> ```
>                     {
>                         sum= sum+ sumfinder(i);
> ```

Here you could have an early-abort if the partial digit sum of prime factors already exceeds the digit sum of the original number. That same idea carries over into the suggested rewrites of the method.

> ```
>         if (sumfinder(n)== sum)
>
>             return true; 
>
>         else
>             return false;
> ```

Those six lines could be simplified to `return sumfinder(n) == sum;`

---

> ```
>     static void display()throws InputMismatchException
> ```

Um. If the method is called `display`, I expect it to do output. Why is it throwing an *input*-related exception?

Answer (score 2):

To factorize an integer, you only need to loop over factors between `2` and `sqrt(num)`. If `n` is a prime, `num` will be equal to `n` now. If `num` is not `1` now, it is a prime factor too.

```
import java.util.*;
class Check {
    static long sumDigits(long n) {
        long sum = 0;
        while (n != 0) {
            sum += n % 10;
            n /= 10;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    static boolean checkSmith(long n) {
        long sum = 0, num = n;
        for (long i = 2; i * i <= num; i++) {
            while (num % i == 0) {
                // i is a prime here
                sum += sumDigits(i);
                num /= i;
            }
        }
        if (n == num && n > 1) {
            System.out.println(n + " is a prime number");
            return false;
        }
        System.out.println(n + " is not a prime number");
        if (num > 1) {
            // num is a prime here
            sum += sumDigits(num);
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
        System.out.println(sumDigits(n));

        return sumDigits(n) == sum;
    }

    static void display() throws InputMismatchException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
        long n = sc.nextLong();
        if (checkSmith(n))
            System.out.println("Smith number");
        else
            System.out.println("Not a Smith number");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just be careful about arithmetic overflow with expressions such as `i * i <= num`.  Consider `1.0 * i * i <= num` instead, to use a type with larger range.

Comment: @TobySpeight True. However, `double` has less precision. Why is it correct (especially for square of large primes)? I'd use `&& i <= 3037000499` instead.

Comment: In the cases where you lose the precision (and it matters), I believe you end up with `1.0 * i * i == num` when mathematically `i² ≆ num`, so the loop continues at least as far as it should (it doesn't matter if we perform an extra iteration - we won't hit another factor).  Your suggestion of testing that `i` is less than the root of a maximal `long` is probably better (though I'd want to give a meaningful name to the constant), or you could test `i <= Math.sqrt(num)` - but you'd probably want to cache that root and update it when you change `num`.

Comment: Oh, and if you use `sqrt()`, you probably want to round or ceil it before use!

Comment: It's probably a good idea to add `if (n <= 1) return;` at the start of the function, so we correctly reject negative numbers and 0 and 1 (which are neither prime nor composite), and the prime test can simply be `if (n==num)`.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas for improvment:

1. In `checkprime`, you don't have to loop from 1 to n, looping from 1 to sqrt(n) is enough.
2. The `outer` loop is very inefficient. 
   First, every time you find a factor, you start from the beginning looking for more factors, invoking `checkprime` on number which you already checked.
   Second, I wouldn't bother checking `checkprime` on any number from 1 to n, I would do so for divisors.

a more efficient loop would be:

```
 for(long  i = 1; i<= num ; i++)
    {
        if(num%i== 0 && checkprime(i))
        {
           sum= sum+ sumfinder(i); 
           num = num/i; 
           if (num == 1)
           {
               break outer; 
           }
        }
        i--; //check same factor again
    }
```

Comment: I made the changes you told me to but it still takes too much time.

Comment: Why call `checkprime` on the divisor? It's guaranteed to return `true`, because if `i` is composite then you have already have factored all of its prime divisors out of `num`.